# Rails 3.1.3 deployment assets pipeline served as in development

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3.1, asset-pipeline

I have a Rails 3.1.3 app with assets pipeline enabled.

I set up deployment with capistrano and nginx + unicorn on a Ubuntu 10.04 machine.

App is deployed correctly but assets are served as in development even if they are correctly precompiled on the deployment server.

It seems like app is starting in development on the deployment machine.

on the ubuntu machine I set a

```
RAILS_ENV=production variable in /etc/environment
```

in deploy.rb

```
set :rails_env, :production
```

in unicorn.rb

```
env = ENV["RAILS_ENV"] || "development"
```

Do you have any idea on where to start to solve this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unicorn sets `RACK_ENV`, not `RAILS_ENV`.  In your unicorn.rb use:

```
env = ENV["RACK_ENV"] || "development"
```

I just had this problem as well and found the information on the unicorn site.